# Installing pop3 and smtp mail server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

So, I'm pretty new to linux.  I managed to install php, mysql, and apache as well as setup my domain name and what not.

Until now I thought linux would be a breeze.  I'm trying to install a mail server that will allow me to receive and send mail from "anyaccount@mydomain.com". I've tried following a few postfix guides but I get lost completely.

Are there any good guides out there for beginners?  And what are the recommended software packages for both receiving and sending e-mail? Thanks!

Comment: I really like exim + dovecot for smtp, pop, and imap.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/email-services.html)?  The Postfix + Dovecot setup is rather simple to set up (and so is the Exim one, I presume).

Also, like [Andreas Rehm](https://serverfault.com/questions/174548/installing-pop3-and-smtp-mail-server-on-ubuntu/174562#174562) I want to warn you that running a secure & safe mail server is not simple without knowing how SMTP, DNS , etc. work, and what the possible pitfalls are (this is the same on Windows or any other OS!).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading some articles on howtoforge.

They are easy to read and understand for beginners.

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu8.04-lts

But you should start reading about security - it's not the easiest thing to have a secure server running... You need to understand what threats you need to take care of.